# Como fazer um comparador de listas

Tags: c#, batch

Queria saber como posso fazer um comparador de listas em C# ou bat, para identificar apenas os itens diferentes entre elas

Comment: Coloque na publicação o que você já tentou fazer até agora.

Comment: Bem vindo ao **SO**, essa tarefa seria para comparar linhas rum um arquivo, e, apontando as linhas e seu conteúdo que diferem das outras?

Answer (score 1):

> - **Se entendi a pergunta, onde entendo que queres:**

**1)** usar um solução em **bat/cmd** como opção;

**2)** quer separar itens **duplicados** e **únicos** do conteúdo de um arquivo;

> - Para usar, você pode passar como argumento nome de arquivo alvo pela linha de comando, ou apenas arrastar e soltar esse arquivo alvo direto no **cmd/bat**.

---

```
@echo off & mode con cols=45 lines=8 & cd /d "%~dp0" & color 9f & title Q382159 <nul & set _lf=^

<nul <nul & cd /d "%~dp0" & type nul >"%~dp0Duplicados.log" & type nul >"%~dp0Unicos.log" & echo/

echo/%cmdcmdline%|findstr /i "\.cmd \.bat" 2>nul >nul && set "_1=&echo/no% _lf% Drag ^& Drop " || set "_1=&echo/no% _lf%" Argumento/Parametro"

if /i "%~1^|"=="^|%~1" goto :^(

echo/Comparando conteudo do arquivo... && findstr /ixg:"%~1" "%~1" >>"%~dp0Duplicados.log" 
echo/Separando item/linha/conteudo unicos && findstr /vixg:"%~1" "%~1" >>"%~dp0Unicos.log"

set /a _cnt_unico=0, _cnt_multi=0

for %%C in (Duplicados.log Unicos.log) do for /f %%i in ('type "%~dp0%%C"^|find "" /v /c')do echo/Total itens em %%C: %%i
timeout /t -1 & exit /b

:^( 
echo/Nenhum arquivo usado informado %_1% & echo/ & echo/Sistema em Pause... & >nul timeout /t -1 && exit /b
```

---

**`| Resulta: |`**

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é exatamente isso que quer, mas só pra você ter ideia de por onde começar:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // ------- Criação de Propriedades e Populando elas para o exemplo --------
          // Listas
          var lst1 = new List<int>();
          var lst2 = new List<int>();

          // Add itens na lista 1
          lst1.Add(1);
          lst1.Add(2);
          lst1.Add(3);

          // Add itens na lista 2
          lst2.Add(2);
          lst2.Add(4);
        // ------- FIM --------

        // Compara as listas e add os valores diferentes em outra lista
        var lstDiferencas = (lst1.Except(lst2)).Union(lst2.Except(lst1)).ToList();

        // Imprime os valores da lista 3 (valores diferentes)
        Console.WriteLine("Valores diferentes entre as listas: ");

        // Imprime os valores ordenados
        foreach (var item in lstDiferencas.OrderBy(x=>x))
           Console.WriteLine(item+"; ");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Aqui, pratica do exemplo acima: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ash9mR